# How to get only first part of the date ('DD') from an entire date?

Tags: servicenow

I've converted a date into string. Now, I want to parse a string to get the `DD` part from `DD-MM-YYYY`.

For e.g.

If the date is `03-05-2017` (`DD-MM-YYYY`) then the goal is to get only first part of the string i.e. `03` (`DD`).

Comment: Because the `DD-MM-YYYY` format is fixed length, so you can substring it.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this question as a ServiceNow question, so I assume you're using the ServiceNow GlideDateTime Class to derive the date as a string. If that is correct, did you know that you can actually derive the day of the month directly from the GlideDateTime object? You can use the [getDayOfMonth()](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=geneva&id=r_GDT-getDayOfMonth), [getDayOfMonthLocalTime()](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=geneva&id=r_GDT-getDayOfMonthLocalTime), or [getDayOfMonthUTC()](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=geneva&id=r_GDT-getDayOfMonthUTC).

You could of course, also use [String.prototype.indxOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to get the first hyphen's location, and then return everything up to that location using [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Or, if you're certain that the day of the month in the string will contain an initial zero, you can simply .slice() out a new string from index 0 through index 2.

```
var date = '03-05-2017';
var newDate = date.slice(0, 2);
console.log(newDate); //==>Prints "03".
var alternateNewDate = date.slice(0, date.indexOf('-'));
console.log(alternateNewDate); //==>Prints "03".
```

Comment: I was unable to use any function of GlideDateTime object. It was giving me 'null' output. that's the reason I had to convert a date type into string and then again into an integer to perform some operations.

Comment: Then my other suggestions ought to work for you, such as the script clippings at the bottom. :-)